# Box.net data access through attachements.me ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, box-api

Can anyone please have some tutorial or link for accessing Box.net API through attachements.me ruby gem?

I want to access box data though attachements.me ruby gem from  Ruby on Rails application but I don't understand where to start.

I created a new rail app and want to add attachements.me ruby gem. I updated the gem file and installed bundle.

I will have to authenticate users but cant understand where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading through their great documentation here: https://github.com/attachmentsme/ruby-box

A great place to begin is authenticating a user.  You need to redirect them to the `authorize_url` after they click a button or link in one of your views to connect their Box account.

Box will send a code with the redirect URI that you need to capture to create this instance variable: `@token = session.get_access_token('code-returned-to-redirect_url')`

Once you do this, use the `@token` instance variable to create a `session = RubyBox::Session.new`

To understand what is going on behind the scenes, I'd also recommend reading through the Box documentation here: http://developers.box.com/oauth/